# Distorted UI after update to 11.0

Tags: update, settings

I have just updated to 11.0 and the UI appears like this:

[image: fugly]

You can't see it but in the pixelated part, the middle part of the right side has the toolbar buttons that are obscured by the horrendous suggestions. They don't disappear after the address is entered, so what you see there is the actual active area of the window. And this is with `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx=1`, but I prefer using `1.25` (or so).

After several tries I managed to track down the culprit as being the unchecking of the "*Always use private browsing mode*" setting. It doesn't happen with the setting checked, and the UI reverts to the usual one if the setting is checked back. Even though it shouldn't matter, I use it so because I'd like to remember the visited sites but without any of the cookies & co. Is there a quick fix or is it a bug?

Comment: I should have added that this is the Linux version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was known [and listed](https://blog.torproject.org/new-release-tor-browser-11-0) in the Tor blog, and also had a [bug report](http://eweiibe6tdjsdprb4px6rqrzzcsi22m4koia44kc5pcjr7nec2rlxyad.onion/tpo/applications/tor-browser/-/issues/40690). The newest update to 11.0.1 seems to have fixed the problem (at the very least I haven't noticed any adverse effects).